# Git repositories in Gemfile.lock each time in different order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gemfile.lock

I have some gems from git repositories in my rails project Gemfile. When I do "bundle install" they saved in some order in Gemfile.lock.

Example:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/wr0ngway/graylog2_exceptions.git
  revision: 797924acd1aa89852605230812d8cfd27da90969
  specs:
    graylog2_exceptions (1.3.0)
      gelf (~> 1.3)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/EppO/rolify.git
  revision: 45de8cf4bf51e60accddee3385829a2266709cb0
  ref: 45de8cf
  specs:
    rolify (3.3.0.rc5)
```

When I run the project or do "bundle install" later it seems what these gems are saved in another order in Gemfile.lock.

Example:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/EppO/rolify.git
  revision: 45de8cf4bf51e60accddee3385829a2266709cb0
  ref: 45de8cf
  specs:
    rolify (3.3.0.rc5)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/wr0ngway/graylog2_exceptions.git
  revision: 797924acd1aa89852605230812d8cfd27da90969
  specs:
    graylog2_exceptions (1.3.0)
      gelf (~> 1.3)
```

Gems revisions are the same but their order in Gemfile.lock is different.
Gemfile.lock is under version control and it marks it as "modified" very frequently. Is there any way to solve this issue to avoid permanent Gemfile.lock modifying?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bug in an older version of bundler, try updating it with:

```
gem update bundler
```